# Upgraded SQL Server from Express to Developer, but still can't use developer server in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I initially installed SQL Server 2019 Express and then upgraded to Developer, but when connecting in SSMS I can't use the dot (`.`) to connect to local server and instead need to use `COMPUTERNAME/SQLEXPRESS`.

Why can't I use anything other than `SQLEXPRESS` to connect to local SQL Server on PC?

[image]

Comment: SQL Server installs as a *named instance* called `SQLEXPRESS`. `.` connects you to the *default instance*. If you've upgraded that named instance to Developer, it's still a named instance.

Comment: As I suspect I know what the follow on question is: No, you can't change the name of an installed named instance. Microsoft recommends you install a new instance and `RESTORE` the needed databases, etc, you need on it.

Answer (score 2):

Once a named instance, always a named instance. There is no supported method to change a named instance to a default instance or visa-versa.

That said, you can change the named instance (SQLEXPRESS) port number(s) to the default 1433 port via SQL Server Configuration Manager-->SQL Server Network Connections-->Protocols for SQLEXPRESS. Clients that connect with TCP/IP specifying only the computer name will connect to the SQLEXPRESS named instance (actually Developer Edition in your case).